# How can I protect rusting Tapcons in a seashore installation?

Tags: screws, rust-removal, rust-proofing, rust

We installed some glass railings using Tapcon screws. Few months after installation screws started to rust. The house is located on a seashore, and in windy weather, saltwater spray can reach it.
Replacing all the screws requires taking all railings apart and it is a huge amount of work and I am looking for other options.

What kind of rust inhibitor and/or paint could I apply to the screws to protect them that will be long lasting in a marine environment?

Comment: Since this is a Question & Answer board, not a general discussion forum, I reformulated your question to actually ask a question instead of inviting discussion as discussion is off topic. While you're waiting for an answer, spend a moment to take the [tour] to familiarize yourself with how this site is different from others so you can get the most out of it.

Comment: You better deal with it soon though, or the screws will turn into a hideous bloom of rust that will just snap off at the head when you try to remove it, and that will ruin the site for any other options.  Yeah, seaside corrosion is such a problem that NASA has *a whole website* for it http://corrosion.ksc.nasa.gov.  Someone (probably Kruschkev) sited their main launch base right on the ocean.

Comment: Is the rust on the shaft, or just the head were the coating was damaged during installation? If the former, nothing you paint on will help.

Comment: There is probably rust on both shaft and heads. Replacing these screws will require completely taking apart the railings, probably a few weeks of work. Right now there is only some surface rust on some of the screws, I don't think they are structurally damaged. If rusting is stopped they should be fine. Screws are hidden behind decorative covers, so it doesn't matter if they don't look good. Do you think that covering them entirely in construction silicone will stop corrosion?

Comment: I found rustolium reformer to be the only thing that works at the coast once rusted other than a acid wash to dissolve the rust and repainting. The problem is once the salt is there it’s hard to get rid of it, the reformer product worked respectively well in my opinion was much better than the ugly stains that will show up in a few months if rusting continues.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, any coating you apply will probably be ruined by the act of installing the screws.  You could paint the screw heads after installation, though.

As for coatings, you could spend a lot of money on rust-inhibiting paint, but I've never found it to work any better than good-ol' Krylon or equivalent.  Make sure the coverage is good and re-paint any scratches.

For a more permanent solution for attaching to concrete near the ocean, I would use stainless conrete/masonry anchors.

[image]

Comment: It seems the OP is looking for a post-installation solution since he stated that, "Few months after installation screws started to rust" and "Replacing all the screws ... is a huge amount of work". Care to update to reflect that?

Comment: FWIW, once the Tapcons are rusted, coating them isn't going to fix them.  I understood the initial question to be looking for a solution to keep from having to replace them _again_ since the replacement of the rusted ones is a given.  Since replacing them with threaded anchors isn't _that much_ more work than just backing out the rusted screws and installing new ones, I thought it an acceptable answer.

Comment: You may want to [edit] your answer to explicitly say that, then. Comments may be missed or deleted, so stating it down here isn't as valuable. I do agree - stainless steel hardware is absolutely the way to go in a marine environment.

Comment: Replacing these screws will require completely taking apart the railings, probably a few weeks of work. Right now there is only some surface rust on some of the screws, I don't think they are structurally damaged. If rusting is stopped they should be fine. Screws are hidden behind decorative covers, so it doesn't matter if they don't look good. Do you think that covering them entirely in construction silicone will stop corrosion?

Comment: Encapsulated salt is not the best way to go,  cleaning and using a reformer that chemically alters the rust has worked for me. If you do it prior to them progressing two far it may solve the problem. Possibly after a good cleaning coating with a silicone may work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace them with Monel; seashore boat hardware stores will carry a variety of monel hardware. Cupro-nickel ( 70 copper, 30 nickel; US coinage alloy) will work , not as common , not as strong. SS 316 is adequate but will rust: it sounds like your original hardware was 316. Any coating or galvanizing is temporary. Ships will use some Navel brass and Admiralty brass ( do the names give you a hint ?)  , not as strong as monel or cupro-nickel and you need a crew of sailors to polish them or they turn green.

Comment: The price of nickel more than doubled this week; You may be able to get the older price on Monel ( 70 % Ni)  current inventory if you hurry to the boat supply . I doubt "big box" stores will have Monel.

Comment: _Wonders why a change in raw material price today impacts the retail sales price of a product made with lower priced raw material months ago. Takes question off to [money.se]._